# HighCharts Combination Chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using combination charts in highcharts [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHC6R/1/). Above a certain point the pie chart comes in the way of line chart and hinder its visibility.

How can I push the pie chart up/down dynamically based upon the value of line chart.

Here is my highcharts code.

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Combination chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var s;
                    if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                        s = ''+
                            this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                    } else {
                        s = ''+
                            this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            labels: {
                items: [{
                    html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                    style: {
                        left: '40px',
                        top: '8px',
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                }]
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'Average',
                data: [3, 6, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fillColor: 'white'
                }
            }, {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Total consumption',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    y: 13,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    y: 23,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    y: 19,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
                }],
                center: [100, 80],
                size: 100,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

I want somthing like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo). You see pie chart and spline are not clashing. But in my case, the value of spline being high, the pie chart hinders the visibility of spline. Pie chart should automatically adjust itself somewhere above or below the spline.

How can I do this?

Comment: what exactly you want. plz give sample of output.

Comment: I want somthing like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo). You see pie chart and spline are not clashing. but in my case, the value of spline being high, the pie chart hinders the visibility of spline. Pie chart should automatically adjust itself somewhere above or below the spline.

Comment: I think you can consider another solution: use two different charts, one for pie and one for spline. Now use some draggable plugin for pie container, and user will be allowed to move around that pie. If you have only 6 categories you may find some required space for pie, but sometime it may be impossible.

Comment: @PawełFus- Your solution doesn't seem to work at industrial level and is not standard.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by: "is not standard"? To put this clear - Highcharts doesn't have such feature like: "position my pie chart according to another spline series".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an automatic way. You may have to add some logic to set the center and size parameters of the chart depending on the data being plotted.

Another way is to extend the y axis to make room. You can calculate this based on the max value being plotted plus enough space for the pie chart:

```
 yAxis: {
            max:10
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7GMr/

Comment: There is no specific space that I can provide. Even if I provide double the space(in some cases), then even the pie chart overlaps the line chart. Moreover, giving a maximum limit will not provide me much of information from the spline as the spline size will be decreased making it difficult to interpret the data points.